# How to validate hostname (may be IP) and port number (CString)

Tags: validation, mfc, port, ip, hostname

I have an dialog for HTTP proxy configuration with hostname and port edit boxes.

My question is how can I validate user input for correct hostname and port?

May be I have to use some regular expression for hostname validation or there is some helpful MFC or WinAPI function? What is the maximum correct number for port?

Comment: This question is in serious need of more information in order to give helpful answers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Port number is an unsigned short from 1-65535, ports under 1024 are reserved for system services http, ftp, etc.
2. I don't believe that you can [validate host name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname#Restrictions_on_valid_host_names) (or should) especially when you have locallized host names.

Comment: Privileged ports are those below 1024, not 256.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Apache Commons Validator's InetAddressValidator. Check out http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/InetAddressValidator.html.

That project has many validator utilities you can reuse. Hope it helps.